# create a Property-Sheet that can Add-Reference in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, propertysheet

Is it possible to [**Add Reference**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) to a project in Visual Studio 2015 using [**Property Sheet**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh442833.aspx)?
 How?

This below image (**Add Reference**) is what I want, but I want to do it using **Property Sheet**.

[image]

This feature probably doesn't exist anymore :-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx

> The Common Properties configurations in earlier versions of Visual
>   Studio have been removed. To add a reference to a project, you now use
>   the Add Reference dialog in the same way as for managed languages. See
>   Managing references in a project.

Is there still a workaround?
I want to create a magic property-sheet, then "just include a certain property-sheet, and everything will work!" (without need to **Add References** manually).

It can also reduce cost to maintain / refactor project.

Comment: In the end Add Reference just adds some lines to the project file (<ProjectReference>... IIRC). Open the project file with a text editor, cut the text created by Add reference and paste in into a property sheet.

Comment: @stijn  Oh my god, you again, if can cut & paste that, it would be a nice solution too.  I will test it in a few days.   I can see the tag in `.vcxproj`.   Thank a lot!  Are you god?  I will set your blog (if you show) as my favorite page.

Comment: sorry no god and no blog :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing Add Reference in VS does is adding something like this

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="path\to\project.vcxproj">
    <Project>{e4abca85-42b0-4168-a628-e2287b9a8763}</Project>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

to the project file. That is just standard msbuild code so you can put it in a property sheet (which after all is just another name for an 'msbuild file') like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="path\to\project.vcxproj">
      <Project>{e4abca85-42b0-4168-a628-e2287b9a8763}</Project>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and it would have the same effect; when building, that is. It doesn't play well with the gui in VS though: it will see the reference but I don't think it is able to modify it (like setting CopyLocal) in the property sheet so adjustments liek that have to be done manually. Then again, seems like a small price to pay if you want the reusability a property sheet offers.

Comment: I tested, it works! It causes a trivial glitch when I remove some reference using Solution Explorer "one or more errors occurred", but it is what to be expected.   .....  The `<Project>{e4abca85-42b0-4168-a628-e2287b9a8763}</Project>` is a little scary for cut/paste though, not sure what it means.  As far as I know, it is "GUID".  Can I delete it (i.e. not paste that part)?

Comment: It is the GUID of the referred project. When deleted the reference in the ui gets a yellow exclamation mark, but I don't know if there are any other consequences. You could always try and see if builds still work.

Comment: I believe you can answer this propersheet question too. I am curious. Thank. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636185/append-path-of-many-visual-studio-property-sheets-props-additively )